# How to have several embeded font in a html textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm building a as3 application which displays a textfield with html text inside.
I need to embed the font to have the same aspect on any device.

So I have:

```
var Arial:Font=new ArialClass();
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myFormat.font=Arial.fontName;
texte = new TextField();
texte.embedFonts=true;
texte.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
```

The problem is that if there's a word in bold it will be displayed like the rest of the text.
Can I add several font to the textformat ?

Thanks

Comment: Use **TextField.htmlText** property: texte.htmlText = '<font face="Arial">Arial <b> Bold </b> <i> Italic </i> <b><i> Bold Italic </i></b> </font>'; As long as you have all of them embedded into the SWF (or available through the system) it should work.

Comment: This is what I did but it doesn't work, the text stays in normal...

Comment: It only works when I don't embed the font.

Comment: i always had some weird kinds of trouble using the flash dialoge to embed fonts but as soon as i used the embed tag it usually worked. https://divillysausages.com/2011/02/17/as3-font-embedding-masterclass/ maybe this helps